# Galería en jQuery, problema al abrir y cerrar "Modal"

Tags: php, jquery, modal

Intento crear una galería, en la que al pinchar sobre la imagen principal se abre una ventana `modal`, en la que el modal es el propio `div`, simplemente, por jquery, le cambio las clases y obtiene la apariencia de modal.

La función que intento lograr es la siguiente:

Al estar la galería cerrada, pincho en la imagen principal, y abre la galería, si vuelve a pinchar en la imagen principal, se cierra la galería, y así debería suceder infinito.

**La galería abre, después cierra, pero no vuelve a abrir.**

Este es mi código:

```
$('.galeria').click(function() {
    if (screen.width > 481) {
         //$('body').addClass('bloqueado');
         $('.msgGaleriaDesk').hide();
         $('#galPpal').removeClass('col-2');
         $('#galPpal').addClass('modal');
         $('#iGrande').addClass('open');
         $('#iGrande').removeClass('galeria');
         //$("div.imgThumbs").scrollLeft(300);

        $('.open').click(function() {
            console.log(screen);
             //$('body').addClass('bloqueado');
             $('#galPpal').removeClass('modal');
             $('#galPpal').addClass('col-2');
             $('#iGrande').addClass('galeria');              
        });
    }
});
```

Este es el HTML:

```
<div id="imgGrande" class="DivImgGrande">
    <span id="cerrarModal" class="cerrar">&times;</span>
     <?php
     echo '<img id="iGrande" class="imgGrande galeria" src="'.$arr_img_prin['big'].'" alt="'.$arr_img_prin['alt'].' width="100%">';
     ?>
</div>
```

Según el jQuery, al abrir, añade a la `img`, la clase `open`, y al cerrarlo, se supone que la quita (funciona correctamente) el problema, que no vuelve a abrir la galería después de cerrarla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes dos problemas, el primero es que estas usando un solo ID para todas tus imagenes, algo que te puede generar problemas, y el segundo es que no estas quitando la clase `.open` de la imagen una vez que vuelves a dar click en la imagen para cerrarla.

Te dejo el codigo JS corregido:

```
$('body').on('click', '.galeria', function() {
    if (screen.width > 481) {
         //$('body').addClass('bloqueado');
         $('.msgGaleriaDesk').hide();
         $('#galPpal').removeClass('col-2');
         $('#galPpal').addClass('modal');
         $('#iGrande').addClass('open');
         $('#iGrande').removeClass('galeria');
         //$("div.imgThumbs").scrollLeft(300);

        $('body').on('click', '.open', function() {
            console.log(screen);
             //$('body').addClass('bloqueado');
             $('#galPpal').removeClass('modal');
             $('#iGrande').removeClass('open'); // Quitamos la etiqueta open de la imagen
             $('#galPpal').addClass('col-2');
             $('#iGrande').addClass('galeria');              
        });
    }
});
```

También te recomiendo uses `$('body').on('click', '.open', function() {});` en lugar de `$('.open').click(function(){});` ya que este último no funciona correctamente cuando modificas clases o generar elementos nuevos en el doom. [Te dejo aquí](https://programandoointentandolo.com/2017/06/control-eventos-jquery-elementos-dinamicos.html) un link donde se explica mejor esto.

Saludos!

Comment: Genial!! Si funciona correctamente! Agradezco mucho tu ayuda, muchas gracias Jesús.

Comment: De nada, saludos!

Answer (score 2):

[Puedes intentar con la función de `toggleClass`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/).